# Add a new unique ObjectId to each document in collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an existing collection `users` where the `_id` field is a string instead of an `ObjectId`.

Is there a query that can update all documents in the collection and add a unique `ObjectId` for each document to using a new field called `UID`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate a new `ObjectId` using `new ObjectId()` in the shell.

```
db.users.find().forEach(function(doc){
    doc.UID = new ObjectId();
    db.users.save(doc);
})
```

Comment: Updated the answer. This will update documents with unique UID.

Comment: How would you change this to add an ObjectId to embedded documents in an array?